# Installing Ubuntu/Debian on 16 GB SD Card

Tags: debian, ubuntu, system-installation, sd-card

Is it possible to install Ubuntu/Debian on my 16 GB SD Card ? Do I just during installation process chose my SD Card partition and install it (that doesn't work if we have USB) or do I need to install persistance ISO on my SD Card ? The last question how it's with the speed of such demon as this ? I will use that SD Card in laptop slot where I can insert it so I think it should be faster than using USB Adapter.

Comment: Why not? Just fire it up.

Comment: I would not expect it to be *faster* than USB though.  If you have a [USB 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.0) port in the laptop, [SDHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#SDHC) card speeds are not nearly that fast.  If it's USB 2.0, they'll be about the same.

Answer (score 3):

For what it concerns Ubuntu you can search to follow what in [Portable installed system that boots in UEFI as well as BIOS mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).

You can find instructions on how to make an installed system (typically in a USB pendrive) that works with UEFI and BIOS, and is small enough to work in an undersized 8 GB pendrive (7.8 GB). So in a 16 it will be large ;-)

The more general page about [how to install Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) in the main site. They keep it updated.
There are many blog around in the web that can help you. One that you can find interesting is [Installing Ubuntu To USB Drives](http://www.fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/installubuntutousbdrive.html).

For Debian  probably you will chose to install *Debian Live with Persistence*. If you start from windows you can find useful [this post](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/debian-live-flash-drive-install-from-windows/).

An old but always official page about Debian and USB can be [this one](https://wiki.debian.org/BootUsb).

Now some words about speed.
Short version: **test it**.
Not so short version: **test it** because each hardware is different.
On one of the laptop that I used there were two USB port. One was a USB 2.0. The second was a USB 1.1. A notable difference.
On more modern laptop you can find USB 2.0 as often as USB 3.0 or 3.1.

To have some hints about speed you can refer to [a list of the bit rates of the devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates).

The class of the memory support that you decide to use will have its incidence too.
**Sdcard** gives informations about [the speed class of the SD cards](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/), wikipedia follows and is [more explicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speed_class_rating).

It's possible that at the end of all your reading you will decide to test it. Did I said it to you before? :-)